# Date error when updating sql database using vb.net 2010 pro

Tags: vb.net

I get the following error when trying to update my sql database.

> SqlDateTime over flow must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12-31-9999 11:59:59 PM

In SQL I have my UP_DATE field set to `datetime2(0)`

Below is my class setup. I removed some info to shorten this question up.

```
Public Class Riders
Private m_RIDER_NO As Integer
Private m_UP_DATE As Date

Public Property UP_DATE() As Date
    Get
        Return m_UP_DATE
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Date)
        m_UP_DATE = value
    End Set
End Property
```

In my update function code:

```
If IsDate(newRider.UP_DATE) Then
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewUP_DATE", newRider.UP_DATE)
 Else
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewUP_DATE", DBNull.Value)
End If
```

Now if I change my class to the below it works fine, as a STRING sql excepts the update.

```
Private m_UP_DATE As String

Public Property UP_DATE() As String
    Get
        Return m_UP_DATE 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_UP_DATE = value
    End Set
End Property
```

1. Anyone know if this is exceptable or will I run into problems later on.
2. Why dose sql except the updates when I have set my UP_DATE field to string in VB, and as datetime2(0) in sql.

Answer (score 0):

Using a .NET string for dates is a fine way to do it to avoid the default date issue with the `Date` data type. And SQL Server will accept any data type it can convert without causing data loss. Converting a string to a date is no problem.